# How to pass data to dompdf?

Tags: php, zend-framework, dompdf

I need to pass data to my template of pdf :

So I initialize my variable with 0 value but even that I have data in DB I get always 0 as final value;

It's not because of DB because even if I do just $ProductProd +=1 I get 0 also

```
$ProductProd = 0 ;
foreach ($Products as $key => $Product) {​

$ProductProd += $Product->getNbrPaquet();
}​
ob_start();
$view='';
require($view);
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_get_clean();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream('pdf.pdf',array("Attachment" => 0));
```

Any one can help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$view='';
require($view);
```

Maybe you want to require a real view such as file called `require('view.php');` here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:

```php
foreach ($Products as $key => $Product) {​
    $ProductProd += $Product->getNbrPaquet();
}​
```

with:

```php
foreach ($Products as $Product) {​
    $ProductProd += $Product->getNbrPaquet();
}​
```

Comment: didn't worked ; I got always 0 (The value that I initialize with )